# БД городов и улиц Украины

Tags: python, mysql, json, xml

Делаю бота в телеграмме, нужно при вводе первых букв вывести город, также само с улицами.
Для начала мне нужна БД городов и улиц Украины. Подскажите пожалуйста, любая информация по теме будет полезна.
Спасибо..

Comment: В чём собственно вопрос-то? В поиске базы городов или в выводе чего-то в телеграм?

Answer (score 2):

Можно по API взять у Новой почты список [областей](https://devcenter.novaposhta.ua/docs/services/556d7ccaa0fe4f08e8f7ce43/operations/556d9130a0fe4f08e8f7ce48), [городов](https://devcenter.novaposhta.ua/docs/services/556d7ccaa0fe4f08e8f7ce43/operations/556d885da0fe4f08e8f7ce46) и [улиц](https://devcenter.novaposhta.ua/docs/services/556d7ccaa0fe4f08e8f7ce43/operations/556d8db0a0fe4f08e8f7ce47).

Сколько пользовался - не замечал проблем с данными.

Comment: Можем связаться в телеге? Тебе не сложно будет там ответить на парочку вопросов?

Comment: Для этого есть SO, может кто-то ответит кто будет свободен и знает ответ, на личные консультации времени нет, работа.